# Tensorflow Merge Datasets Alternatively

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

So I am writing a GAN in tensorflow, and need the discriminator and generator to be objects. Now I am having problems with creating the training dataset for the discriminator.

Currently the relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
self.dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((self.y_,self.x_)) #creates dataset
self.fake_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((self.x_fake_)) #creates dataset

self.dataset=self.dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE) #shuffles
self.fake_dataset=self.fake_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE) #shuffles

self.dataset=self.dataset.repeat().batch(self.batch_size) #batches      
self.fake_dataset=self.fake_dataset.repeat().batch(self.batch_size) #batches

self.iterator=tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(self.dataset.output_types,self.dataset.output_shapes) #creates iterators  
self.fake_iterator=tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(self.fake_dataset.output_types,self.fake_dataset.output_shapes) #creates iterators   

self.x=self.iterator.get_next() 
self.x_fake=self.fake_iterator.get_next() 

self.dataset_init_op = self.iterator.make_initializer(self.dataset,name=self.name+'_dataset_init')  
self.fake_dataset_init_op=self.fake_iterator.make_initializer(self.fake_dataset,name=self.name+'_dataset_init')
```

What I need is for the function to alternatively give one batch of self.x, followed by one batch of self.x_fake.

Is there an easy way to do this, or will I have to results to a counter and an if statement?

Comment: Do you need to alternate datasets between calls to `run` (that is, in one call to `run` you get `x`, the next call `x_fake`) or within the same call to `run` (that is, in the same call to `run` you want to get `x` first and `x_fake` later)?

Comment: @jdehesa in the same call ideally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding exactly what you need, but if you want to get use the different iterators alternatively in the same call that would be defined at graph construction time, and so you could use Python logic to choose the iterator you need. For example:

```
def __init__(self):
    # Make graph and iterators...
    self._use_fake_batch = False

def next_batch(self):
    iter = self.fake_iterator if self._use_fake_batch else self.iterator
    self._use_fake_batch = not self._use_fake_batch
    return iter.get_next()
```

Or without an additional variable, using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

def __init__(self):
    # Make graph and iterators...
    self._iterators = chain.from_iterable(repeat((self.iterator, self.fake_iterator)))

def next_batch(self):
    return next(self._iterators).get_next()
```

Comment: Thank you, the itertools option is exactly what I wanted

Comment: I'm now having an issue using the itertools option that the type returned by next_batch() is a tuple, while I need it to be a tensor. Do you have any idea how this can be resolved?

Comment: @JoeBuckley As I see, `self.dataset` has elements with two components (so `get_next` of its iterator will return a tuple of tensors), whereas `self.fake_dataset` has elements with a single component (so `get_next` of its iterator will return a tensor). I suppose that if you want to use both iterators indistinctly is because they are somehow compatible, but you need to transform the dataset to have the same output type, according to what makes sense in your case.